# Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 5Ghz Issue

Tags: networking, 16.04, atheros

I bought an Asus Hero Alpha motherboard that comes with an Atheros Wireless Card, the card is the following:

```
Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
```

The card works perfectly on 2.4Ghz (Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 and 16.10), the issues start when using 5Ghz. The speed many times drops really fast (Does not disconnect) and stays down, we are talking about an Internet or Lan speed that typically is around 100Mbps it goes all the way down to 1.5Mbps.

The only issues I have found when doing a quick `dmesg` were (Here is a summary of dmesg plus the errors):

```
[ 8281.488634] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 8281.488638] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 8281.488641] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 8281.488643] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 8281.488646] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 8281.488649] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 8281.488652] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 8281.488654] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 8281.488656] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[ 8281.508915] ath10k_pci 0000:09:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[ 8281.746038] ath10k_pci 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:09:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[ 8281.746062] ath10k_pci 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[ 8281.746067] ath10k_pci 0000:09:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[ 8283.924750] ath10k_pci 0000:09:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 (0x05030000, 0x00340aff sub 1043:86e0) fw WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 fwapi 4 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.26 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad
[ 8283.924766] ath10k_pci 0000:09:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[ 8284.001596] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x69
[ 8284.001600] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[ 8284.001603] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[ 8284.001604] ath: Regpair used: 0x69
[ 8284.003776] ath10k_pci 0000:09:00.0 wlp9s0: renamed from wlan0
[ 8284.019349] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s0: link is not ready
[ 8286.279134] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s0: link is not ready
[ 8286.336477] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s0: link is not ready
[ 8290.793388] wlp9s0: authenticate with d0:17:c2:3e:19:f0
[ 8290.846724] wlp9s0: send auth to d0:17:c2:3e:19:f0 (try 1/3)
[ 8290.848417] wlp9s0: authenticated
[ 8290.851753] wlp9s0: associate with d0:17:c2:3e:19:f0 (try 1/3)
[ 8290.854983] wlp9s0: RX AssocResp from d0:17:c2:3e:19:f0 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[ 8290.857737] wlp9s0: associated
```

As you can see, the only issue is:

```
[ 8281.746038] ath10k_pci 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:09:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[ 8281.746062] ath10k_pci 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[ 8281.746067] ath10k_pci 0000:09:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[ 8283.924750] ath10k_pci 0000:09:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 (0x05030000, 0x00340aff sub 1043:86e0) fw WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 fwapi 4 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.26 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad
[ 8283.924766] ath10k_pci 0000:09:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[ 8284.001596] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x69
[ 8284.001600] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
```

I checked and could not find an actual `ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin` file in the system. I do however have all the folder structure for it in `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174` and I even went to https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware to check if there was a `firmware-5.bin` file for the hw3.0 folder, but there was none. So I have a couple of questions regarding this:

1. Is there an actual (or will there be an actual) firmware-5.bin file for hw3.0 or was that a mistake in the code?
2. What could be causing the huge drop of the 5Ghz for this card?

UPDATE: Using 17.04 the Wireless card is worse now. I have a 100Mbit internet connection and now it simply lags all the time. Every minute to 2 minutes the whole wireless card goes to a very slow speed state for several seconds. I also can't change from 2.4Ghz to 5Ghz without having to disable the network altogether and then enable it again.

I am getting this on 17.04 now:

```
TCP: wlp9s0: Driver has suspect GRO implementation, TCP performance may be compromised.
[ 4497.297536] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 11 on unit 2: -110 (exp. 1).
```

Comment: Have you been able to remedy the issue? Has there been another firmware-5.bin file for hw3.0?

Comment: @bkach Not yet but I will keep this question updated for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I am testing the following procedure which could be the answer to the problem in 16.04 and 17.04 for me. If you have this same Atheros model, this is what is working for me on the Asus Maximus Hero Alpha VIII

1. Download the latest `linux-firmware` DEB package from the [Ubuntu Linux Firmware Folder](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/). For me right now since it's May 5 2017, I was able to download [Version 1.165](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.165_all.deb)
2. Install it via dpkg: `sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.165_all.deb`
3. Reboot & Test.

My testing was by doing the following which was failing horribly before:

- Changing from 2.4Ghz to 5Ghz. I have an ASUS AC5300 Router which offers 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz at the same time. The 2.4Ghz SSID is called Ubuntu2G and the 5Ghz is called Ubuntu5G. Changing from one to the other failed, always. Now after changing 8 times after rebooting, the 2.4Ghz to 5Ghz and vice versa is still happening, although now it connects faster and the speed is maintained once I do select which one to connect to and stay with it.
- Streaming something to a Chromecast was a headache. Now I can stream on both, the 2.4Ghz spectrum and the 5Ghz one. It also starts streaming faster. Before I had to wait about 20 to 30 seconds for the streaming to start, now it's about 2 to 3 seconds.
- Downloading from Internet was super slow before. I have 100Mbps speed connection (12MB/s) and the maintained speed was around 1-2MB. Now I am getting 10MB/s to 12MB/s. I have been testing of course for only 20 minutes but I am seeing effective speeds, good connection and a much better overall performance.
- Checking for errors on dmesg when disconnecting, reconnecting, connection. When streaming, when downloading, when uploading, when booting, etc.. So far, after upgrading, am not getting any errors related to the Wireless card.

Current Problems:

- Changing from 2.4Ghz to 5Ghz does not work. Basically the wireless card fails to connect and if I try to go back it fails. Now, changing from 5Ghz to 2.4Ghz does work, but like I mentioned, going back to 5 from 2.4 will fail sometimes.

I will keep everyone posted if this keeps up for the following month.